# How to receive packet upload confirmation with WinRT StreamSockets?

Tags: c#, sockets, windows-8, tcp, windows-runtime

I have a WinRT application which performs uploads using `StreamSocket` and `DataWriter`. It tracks the time the upload takes and then calculates the throughput.

The issue I am having is that I am getting throughputs much higher than Wireshark shows. This is because my upload loop finishes and takes the ending timestamp before the WinRT framework has actually sent the data to the network layer. I have found no means of receiving confirmation from the framework that the packets have actually made it to the network layer. The `DataWriter` `StoreAsync` method only returns the number of bytes you've stored, which I knew before I stored them.

Other frameworks, such as Windows Phone, have a callback in place that gets triggered after your packet is sent and tells you how many bytes you've uploaded. I haven't found any equivalent in WinRT and have had to settle for a loop that records how many bytes I've committed in the `StoreAsync` function.

Is there a way to get confirmation from the framework of when and how many bytes have actually been sent to the network layer?

UPDATE: I gave @polkduran's suggestions a try, and while they helped alleviate some of the packet loss, I am still experiencing significant packet loss in smaller file uploads (100KB). For larger files (4MB and 10MB), all of the packets are being sent, but the end time is still off by a couple seconds, which skews the throughput calculation significantly (when compared to Wireshark traces). My guess is the callback just slowed down the uploads a bit, rather than providing actual packet upload confirmation.

I'm still looking for a solution to this issue.

**EDIT: I created a support ticket with Microsoft about this issue. Their official response is that there is no way in the WinRT framework to confirm that a packet has actually been uploaded.**

Answer (score 2):

I have not tried but you can assign a handler to the [`Completed`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.streams.datawriterstoreoperation.completed) callback property in the [`DataWriterStoreOperation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.streams.datawriterstoreoperation) returned by the [`StoreAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.streams.datawriter.storeasync) method of the [`DataWritter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br208154.aspx) object.

Or

You can use directly the [`WriteAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.streams.ioutputstream.writeasync) method from the [`OutputStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.sockets.streamsocket.outputstream) property from your [`StreamSocket`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br226882.aspx) which return a [`IAsyncOperationWithProgress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br206594.aspx) operation.

Comment: Yes! Your first suggestion was the solution. I was able to use the `Completed` callback of the returned `DataWriterStoreOperation` object to send each packet and call itself rather than sending them in a loop. The `IAsyncOperation<uint>` parameter passed into the callback function has a method called `GetResults` which gives you the bytes sent. This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much! This was a tremendous help to me.

Comment: I spoke too soon, unfortunately. Neither of these solutions actually fix the problem completely. In my first test, I used it in an HTTP upload implementation, so the code was actually waiting to receive the 200 OK from the server before it finished, which forced it to wait the full time. After I attempted to implement this in an FTP upload, it continued to finish the full upload before the server actually received all of the packets when I uploaded smaller file sizes (100KB). I think all this did was slow it down a little, but it isn't true packet upload confirmation.